# Actionscript Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: LocalConnection.send: 127.0.0.1 cannot access

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, localconnection

When running flash components that use localConnection within an HTML container, I get the following error in a popup box (flash player is the debug version):

Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: LocalConnection.send: 127.0.0.1 cannot access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the page's URL from http://127.0.0.1/ to http://localhost/ solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

// add this line after the instanciation aof the receiver file

receiveSwf_lc.allowDomain("localhost");

// or whatever domain you like, use * as wildcard to allow any domain name

Answer (score 0):

also you might want to add a crossdomain.xml file, but here is the decent explaination: http://scottrockers.com/blog/resources/flash-information/workaround-solution-to-flash-error-2044-unhandled-securityerror-and-error-2048-security-sandbox-violation

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hosts file entry and point it to 127.0.0.1 as well.