# downloading image in as3 from client url

Tags: actionscript-3

here is the link of my Flash application 
http://www.asa.com.pk/
hit the above URL and click on the PostCard section shown.. This will show you image and button to download that image. Application works fine at above URL and it downloads the file too but when any user hits the alternate url , the file is not downloaded..
http//asa.com.pk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My debugger shows:

```
Error #2044: SecurityErrorEvent no controlado: text=Error #2048: Violación de la       seguridad Sandbox: http://asa.com.pk/main.swf no puede cargar datos desde http://www.asa.com.pk/downloads/largeimage/mcb.gif.
    at main_fla::MainTimeline/Download_Started()
```

Quick Google Search ended on:

[Actionscript Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: LocalConnection.send: 127.0.0.1 cannot access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477904/actionscript-error-2044-unhandled-securityerrorevent-texterror-2047-securi)

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=148714

I think you will get it after this, basically it's a crossdomain.xml thing.

I have tested your app, and the error it's exactly because of the flash player 10 sandbox feature, you need to use  a crossdomain.xml file where you allow both domains to be cross-accessed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do to fix security errors like this.

- Create a valid crossdomain.xml file under both http://domain.com & http://www.domain.com
- Set the DNS to forward http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com permanently
- In your AS code add Secuirty.allowdomain( "*" );

Hope this helps.