# TextField and Security Sandbox Violation

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am creating a TextField in my flash application, but when i am starting to write something the following error in written to trace:

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain xxx tried to access incompatible context yyy

What is the reason for that? How can i solve it?

Comment: No.

BTW, it is also a problem because while the message is thrown to trace, it seems that i can't detect mouse middle clicks, using ASnative- ASnative(800,2)(4) always return false.

Comment: @Erik Sapir. ASnative? Are you using AS 2 or AS 3? Or both? Or are you trying to talk from a AVM2 (as3) movie directly to a AVM1 (as2) movie?

Comment: Are you using Flex?  Can you share some code?

Comment: I use both AS2 and AS3 (no other way to detect middle click with AS3).

I am using Flex - the code is too complex, and i can't share it.
But i am sure that the scenario is correct.

Comment: @Erik Sapir. Do both swfs communicate with each other. If so, how? An AS 3 swf cannot script an AS 2 swf (at least, not directly)

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477904/actionscript-error-2044-unhandled-securityerrorevent-text-error-2047-securi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error doesn't have much to do with your Textfield. When you enter some text you must be starting some sort of logic that leads to this error. The error itself is pretty clear, some logic in your code seems to be loading some content and indicates a problem with your policy file. It's impossible to help without seeing some code, you need to implement some form of debug routine to try and break your application in different parts, according to each part's concern, in order to try & isolate the error.