# Web control playing youtube video C#

Tags: c#, flash

- I embed a web control in a C# form. And I use the web control to play youtube videos.
- I just upgraded flash player from version 13 => version 18.

I got an error like the following [picture](http://prntscr.com/85i4ie).

> Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: LocalConnection.send: s0.2mdn.net cannot access https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/...

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477904/actionscript-error-2044-unhandled-securityerrorevent-text-error-2047-secur

Comment: I'm not using Action Script to write this app. Is there any way to config to avoid this error? Or some javascript code..

Comment: Try changing the Flash Player's Global Security Settings 
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Tools/FlashPlayerSecuritySetup/HowToSetup.html

Comment: It's a software. I cannot config every computers that our software is installed on.